# Flutter - Scrollable List of Widgets

Tags: flutter

I have a screen that displays a list of widgets, something like this:

```
Column(                              
    children: listW,
),
```

The `listW` object is of type `List<Widget>`. The first index contains a `ListTitle` and all others are of type `Card`. The number of cards are added dynamically. Now the problem is that when the list has lets say 10 `Card` objects, it is hidden below the screen. I need some sort of a `ScrollableView` to contain my list. How can I do that since `SingleChildScrollableView` can bear only one widget. How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you need a ListView widget. This is the most commonly used scrolling widget in Flutter. Check the link: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing you code to this

```
ListView(children: listW,)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ListView()` for this.

```
ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
         //Your widgets
    ]
)
```

Keep in mind, that a list view renders all the items currently in the list, which means huge lists will cause performance issues. You can get around this using a `ListView.builder`, since this creates items as they are scrolled on the screen.

```
class FruitList extends StatelessWidget{
  final List<String> fruits = [ "Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Orange", "Kiwi" ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: _buildFruitItem,
            itemCount: fruits.length,
          )
        )
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFruitItem( BuildContext context, int index ){
    return Card(
      child: Text( fruits[index] ),
    );
  }

}
```

You can checkout more documentation on this here: https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists